# UnderscoreJS to find results in an Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I have a controller setup with an input that takes a Purchase Order number. At the moment to get results I am setting data[0] and always returns the first result.  I want to set up a validation where the the number entered will return the correct result. Before I can do that though I need to iterate through the results to just return the data I need rather than hard-coding it to the first result. I am using underscore and have set up the following but not retrieving the result I want. Please could someone just advice how I use underscore to do this?

Underscore that did not work:

```
            var test = _.map(data, function(data) {
                return {
                    purchaseOrderNumber: data.purchaseOrderNumber
                };
            });

            console.log(test);
```

Console output:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

The html:

```
        <form novalidate name="goodsIssueForm" class="form-group cnc-inline-field">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="purchaseOrderInput" ng-model="purchaseOrderInput" ng-change="resetGoodsIssueValidity()" required></input>
            <button data-auto="rpoBtn" ng-click="getPurchaseOrder()" class="btn btn-primary">Find</button>
        </form>
```

The controller:

```
    $scope.getPurchaseOrder = function() {
        var purchaseOrderNumber = $scope.purchaseOrderInput;

        GoodsIssueService.getPurchaseOrders(purchaseOrderNumber)
        .then(function(data) {
            if ($scope.goodsIssueForm.$valid) {
                $scope.goodsIssueDocument = data;
                $scope.goodsIssueDocument.purchaseOrderNumber = data[0].purchaseOrderNumber;
            }

        })
        .catch(function() {
            $scope.goodsIssueForm.$setValidity('notfound', false);
        });
    };
```

Comment: what does `GoodsIssueService.getPurchaseOrders()` do? You are already passing the number as argument. As far as your `map` goes it will return from all items in array without adding a conditional in it. Using a filter function is what you want

Comment: it's just the service that get's the PO from the API

Comment: but if it's coming from API won't it only contain the data for that number? Not clear what you are needing here

Comment: All I want to to go one layer deeper than I am returning, so now I have [Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object but what I want is results of just 0: Object

Comment: neither filter criteria or data structure are shown ... so still not sure what you need. Also not sure how you are using this in view